# Rails + Rspec + In-Memory Db (Postgres to SQLite) = Error with INET field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, devise

Here i am again!

This time, we are building a new project, and as we started to test it with RSPEC, we started to seen a lot of database logic.

So, a lot of tests adds, removes and updates information from our DB, which is in PostgreSQL.

Predicting an iminent Apocalyptical future for our Testing Suit (which may take tons of minutes to finish in future, since we are using a file-based database), i decided to start the integration of a In-Memory DB.

This is my attempt. (in the end of config block of spec_helper.rb)

```
setup_sqlite_db = lambda do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlite3', database: ':memory:')
  load "#{Rails.root.to_s}/db/schema.rb"
end
silence_stream(STDOUT, &setup_sqlite_db)
```

But when i run the Specs, i get an error at my Schema.rb:

```
"schema.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined method `inet' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x00000004f845e0> (NoMethodError)"
```

This happens because we use Devise (for auth purposes), and Devise have a table with columns of type "INET", which is an specific type of PostgreSQL, which will never work on SQLite.

My Question is: There is some workaround to this problem?

Comment: You should run your tests using the database that you're going to be using in production, ESPECIALLY if you're using database-specific (or non-standard) features.

Comment: Don't use INET if you can't use it because your other database doesn't support it. You loose some functionality and maybe performance, but that happens when you get in a situation like this. The other option would be to use a single brand of database instead of two brands.